# Template operator() specialization for a special type?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++17, c++14

I have a Vector class that is template based.
I have a unit conversion template that is based on [Scott Meyers Dimensional Analysis in C++](http://se.ethz.ch/%7Emeyer/publications/OTHERS/scott_meyers/dimensions.pdf). I'm not going to list it as it is complex, unless the problem can't be solved without those details. I'm using the casting operator for when I need to pass the data to outside functions.

```
template<typename T>
struct XYZVector 
{
  operator Point3D() { return Point3D(x, y, z); }
}
```

If I use T as a double it works fine. But when I do this I need a specialization.

```
Point3D vecOut = XYZVector<Unit::usFoot>(x,y,z);
```

Will fail because when converting a Unit object you need to use an as() method.

```
operator Point3D() { return Point3D( x.as<T>(), y.as<T>(), z.as<T>() ); }
```

So I need someway to say if T is a Unit use this line, other wise use the next line.

```
template<typename T>
struct XYZVector
{
  //if typename T is a Unit type use this
  operator Point3D() { return Point3D( x.as<T>(), y.as<T>(), z.as<T>() ) }
  //otherwise use this
  operator Point3D() { return Point3D(x, y, z); }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if constexpr` to the rescue.

```
operator Point3D() { 

     if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>,Unit>){
          return Point3D(x.as<T>(),y.as<T>(),z.as<T>());
     }else{
          return Point3D(x,y,z);
     }
}
```

Comment: The general idea is solid, but the code is not quite right. `Unit` is not a type. Ideally, this should be handled with a concept, but a `is_unit_type<T>::value` trait type would be more backwards compatible.

Comment: @Frank, the example Staz provided hasn't worked for me and I think you were hinting at that and suggesting a better way. But I'm not sure how to implement it. Could you provide an example? Thanks

Comment: @MarkTwombley I kinda used `Unit` as a placeholder for the type. You can replace it accordingly. Also `std::remove_cvref` is `C++20` type trait. You can use `std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>` instead if your cpp standard is lower than 20.

Comment: Thank you @Staz for that update. I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

I would use overloads as customization point:

```
// overload for built-in type (no ADL)
double to_double(double d) { return d;}

template <typename T>
struct XYZVector
{
    // ...
    operator Point3D() const {
        return Point3D(to_double(x),
                       to_double(y),
                       to_double(z));
    }
};

// The ones which can be found by ADL can be placed after
namespace Unit {
    double to_double(usFoot u) { return u.as<double>(); } 
}
```